# Replace a set of pattern matches with corresponding replacement strings in R

Tags: r, string, replace

The [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)) function in PHP replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string. What interests me the most here, is that if `search` and `replace` args are arrays (in R we call that vectors), then `str_replace` takes a value from each array (vector) and uses them to search and replace on subject.

In other words, does R (or some R package) have a function to perform the following:

```
string <- "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
patterns     <- c("quick", "brown", "fox")
replacements <- c("slow",  "black", "bear")
xxx_replace_xxx(string, patterns, replacements)          ## ???
## [1] "The slow black bear jumped over the lazy dog."
```

So I am seeking for something like `chartr`, but for search patterns and replacement strings of arbitrary number of characters. This cannot be done via one call to `gsub()` as its `replacement` argument can be a single string only, see `?gsub`. So my current implementation is like:

```
xxx_replace_xxx <- function(string, patterns, replacements) {
   for (i in seq_along(patterns))
      string <- gsub(patterns[i], replacements[i], string, fixed=TRUE)
   string
}
```

However, I am looking for something much faster if `length(patterns)` is large - I have a lot of data to process and I'm dissatisfied with the current results.

Exemplary toy data for benchmarking:

```
string <- readLines("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/31536/31536-0.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
patterns <- c("jak", "to", "do", "z", "na", "i", "w", "za", "tu", "gdy",
   "po", "jest", "Tadeusz", "lub", "razem", "nas", "przy", "oczy", "czy",
   "sam", "u", "tylko", "bez", "ich", "Telimena", "Wojski", "jeszcze")
replacements <- paste0(patterns, rev(patterns))
```

Comment: Doesn't your **stringi** package provide this?

Comment: @Thomas: I'm working on that :) scheduled for stringi_0.3-1,see issue [#102](https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/issues/102)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using PCRE instead of fixed matching takes ~1/3 the time on my machine for your example.

```
xxx_replace_xxx_pcre <- function(string, patterns, replacements) {
   for (i in seq_along(patterns))
      string <- gsub(patterns[i], replacements[i], string, perl=TRUE)
   string
}
system.time(x <- xxx_replace_xxx(string, patterns, replacements))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.491   0.000   0.491 
system.time(p <- xxx_replace_xxx_pcre(string, patterns, replacements))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.162   0.000   0.162 
identical(x,p)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: A little bit peculiar, isn't it?

Comment: @gagolews: I don't know. The "Performance Considerations" section of `?gsub` says, "Generally PCRE will be faster than the default regular expression engine, and `fixed = TRUE` faster still (especially when each pattern is matched only a few times)."  I guess this is one of those times that isn't "general". That section also says `useBytes = TRUE` will be faster as well, but I don't know if that's applicable to your actual use case (it makes the PCRE version ~2x faster--running in 0.088s on my machine).

Answer (score 8):

If the patterns are fixed strings made of word characters as in the example then this works.  `gsubfn` is like `gsub` except the replacment argument can be a string, list, function or proto object.  If its a list, as here, it compares the matches to the regular expression with the names and for those that are found it replaces them with the corresponding values:

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\b\\w+\\b", as.list(setNames(replacements, patterns)), string)
## [1] "The slow black bear jumped over the lazy dog."
```

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, its performance (see the toy benchmark data example) is 10x worse than that of my exemplary solution...

Comment: Note that the code in the question replaces the substring quick  of quicker in this case which may not be what you want:  `"The quicker brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."`  The code here handles that correctly.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with stringi >= 0.3-1 by using one of the `stri_replace_*_all` functions with the `vectorize_all` argument set to `FALSE`:

```
library("stringi")
string <- "The quicker brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
patterns     <- c("quick", "brown", "fox")
replacements <- c("slow",  "black", "bear")
stri_replace_all_fixed(string, patterns, replacements, vectorize_all=FALSE)
## [1] "The slower black bear jumped over the lazy dog."
stri_replace_all_regex(string, "\\b" %s+% patterns %s+% "\\b", replacements, vectorize_all=FALSE)
## [1] "The quicker black bear jumped over the lazy dog."
```

Some benchmarks:

```
string <- readLines("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/31536/31536-0.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
patterns <- c("jak", "to", "do", "z", "na", "i", "w", "za", "tu", "gdy",
   "po", "jest", "Tadeusz", "lub", "razem", "nas", "przy", "oczy", "czy",
   "sam", "u", "tylko", "bez", "ich", "Telimena", "Wojski", "jeszcze")
replacements <- paste0(patterns, rev(patterns))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   stri_replace_all_fixed(string, patterns, replacements, vectorize_all=FALSE),
   stri_replace_all_regex(string, "\\b" %s+% patterns %s+% "\\b", replacements, vectorize_all=FALSE),
   xxx_replace_xxx_pcre(string, "\\b" %s+% patterns %s+% "\\b", replacements),
   gsubfn("\\b\\w+\\b", as.list(setNames(replacements, patterns)), string),
   unit="relative",
   times=25
)
## Unit: relative
##                   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
## stri_replace_all_fixed  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    25 
## stri_replace_all_regex  2.169701  2.248115  2.198638  2.267935  2.267635  1.753289    25  
## xxx_replace_xxx_pcre    1.983135  1.967303  1.937021  1.961449  1.974422  1.469894    25  
## gsubfn                 63.067835 69.870657 69.815031 71.178841 72.503020 57.019072    25
```

So, as far as matching only at word boundaries is concerned, the PCRE-based version is the fastest.