# How to replace strings with the matching string from a list?

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, matching

Say I have a column `df1$z` with some "dirty" strings within

```
> df1$z
 [1] alpha uybkh   kilo-mdjfyrs  lima qxaucnpe gamma-qpnej  
 [5] beta-okmwy    beta-uybkh    gamma mdjfyrs lima qxaucnpe
 [9] beta qpnej    kilo okmwy   
9 Levels: alpha uybkh beta-okmwy beta-uybkh ... lima qxaucnpe
```

Some of the strings begin with patterns which are included in another vector `a`.

```
> a
[1] "alpha" "beta"  "gamma"
```

These `a`-matching strings in `z` I want to replace with the corresponding pattern of vector `a` so that the following results:

```
# [1] "alpha"         "kilo-mdjfyrs"  "lima qxaucnpe" "gamma"        
# [5] "beta"          "beta"          "gamma"         "lima qxaucnpe"
# [9] "beta"          "kilo okmwy"
```

I wrote a function that brought me close, but it replaces the strings not at once, and I couldn't manage to put things together:

```
> lapply(seq_along(a), function(x) {z[grep(paste0("^", a[x]), z)] <- a[x]; z})
[[1]]
 [1] "beta sfrmyijl" "lima-xudwfkm"  "lima-kirvpys"  "gamma wriygcb"
 [5] "alpha"         "alpha"         "kilo xudwfkm"  "alpha"        
 [9] "gamma wriygcb" "kilo-wvxgar"  

[[2]]
 [1] "beta"           "lima-xudwfkm"   "lima-kirvpys"   "gamma wriygcb" 
 [5] "alpha wvxgar"   "alpha-sfrmyijl" "kilo xudwfkm"   "alpha-kirvpys" 
 [9] "gamma wriygcb"  "kilo-wvxgar"   

[[3]]
 [1] "beta sfrmyijl"  "lima-xudwfkm"   "lima-kirvpys"   "gamma"         
 [5] "alpha wvxgar"   "alpha-sfrmyijl" "kilo xudwfkm"   "alpha-kirvpys" 
 [9] "gamma"          "kilo-wvxgar"
```

I also failed with some `mapply()` approaches which I think could be helpful here, and looked into some existing answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26676734/6574038) which I couldn't adapt to my specific problem though.

So how would I do this in an efficient *base R* way? *Note* that the replacement should be put back into the data frame `df1` without disturbing the order of the rows.

#### Data

```
a <- c("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
set.seed(105056)
z <- paste0(sample(c(a, "kilo", "lima"), 10, replace=TRUE), 
            sample(c("-", " "), 10, replace=TRUE), 
            replicate(5, paste0(sample(letters, sample(5:9)), collapse="")))
df1 <- data.frame(z, x=rnorm(10))
```

Comment: Try `gsub(paste0(".*\\b(",paste(a, collapse="|"),")\\b.*"), "\\1", df1$z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following `sub` solution:

```
> sub(paste0(".*\\b(",paste(a, collapse="|"),")\\b.*"), "\\1", df1$z)
 [1] "alpha"         "kilo-mdjfyrs"  "lima qxaucnpe" "gamma"         "beta"         
 [6] "beta"          "gamma"         "lima qxaucnpe" "beta"          "kilo okmwy"
```

The pattern will match any chars before and after the keyword in your `a` vector, and will capture the keyword into Group 1 while `\1` replacement pattern will only keep the found keyword and discard all text before and after it. If there is no match, there won't be any change.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WmUkjL/1).

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sub`.  Create a pattern with `paste` after making a single string from 'a', then use it to capture the pattern with backreference (`\\1`) in the replacement

```
sub(paste0(".*\\b(", paste(a, collapse="|"), ")\\b.*"), "\\1", df1$z)
#[1] "alpha"         "kilo-mdjfyrs"  "lima qxaucnpe" "gamma"         "beta"          "beta"          "gamma"        
#[8] "lima qxaucnpe" "beta"          "kilo okmwy"
```

NOTE: `sub` solution was posted first here

---

Or using `str_replace` from `stringr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(z = str_replace(z, 
      paste0(".*\\b(", paste(a, collapse="|"), ")\\b.*"), "\\1"))
#           z           x
#1          alpha -0.18973111
#2   kilo-mdjfyrs -0.88150363
#3  lima qxaucnpe  0.01665189
#4          gamma  0.62647841
#5           beta -0.29526632
#6           beta  0.42480082
#7          gamma  1.03653486
#8  lima qxaucnpe -1.51910745
#9           beta  1.21504343
#10    kilo okmwy  1.25321421
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat longer but less opaque solution, using `ifelse` and `grepl`:

```
df1$z <- ifelse(grepl("alpha.*", df1$z), a[1],
            ifelse(grepl("beta.*", df1$z), a[2],
                   ifelse(grepl("gamma.*", df1$z), a[3], as.character(df1$z))))
df1
               z           x
1          alpha -0.18973111
2   kilo-mdjfyrs -0.88150363
3  lima qxaucnpe  0.01665189
4          gamma  0.62647841
5           beta -0.29526632
6           beta  0.42480082
7          gamma  1.03653486
8  lima qxaucnpe -1.51910745
9           beta  1.21504343
10    kilo okmwy  1.25321421
```