# What is the meaning of %s+% in regex?

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I'm trying to understand the meaning of `%s+%` in this solution

[Replace a set of pattern matches with corresponding replacement strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676045/replace-a-set-of-pattern-matches-with-corresponding-replacement-strings-in-r)

The important part of the code is this

```
xxx_replace_xxx_pcre(string, "\\b" %s+% patterns %s+% "\\b", replacements)
```

I know that `\s+` is used to match one or more spaces, but what is the meaning inside `%%` ?

I tried to use the code without it, because I just want to match inside word boundaries, but it gives an error

```
xxx_replace_xxx_pcre(string, "\\b" patterns "\\b", replacements)
```

I already researched about special PCRE symbols and other things, but didn't find anything. Can anyone give me some explanation about it?

Comment: It is calling a C function `C_stri_join2, e1, e2)`.   Here, it does the `paste0("\\b", patterns, "\\b")`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, where did you find this information?

Comment: You can quote the "%s+%" or backquote and enter on the console to return the code

Comment: If you see something of the form `%...%` in R, it's usually a custom binary operator, e.g. the magrittr `%>%` or the base R `%in%`. These can be defined by the user or by a package. They almost always have help pages, which you can find with either double quotes, `?"%s+%"`, or backquotes, similar to what akrun said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does a concatenation with a call to C function.  We can check the source code from console by backquoting the operator

```
library(stringi)
`%s+%`
function (e1, e2) 
{
.Call(C_stri_join2, e1, e2)
}
```

Based on the behavior of the output, it seems that the C function is an optimized version of `paste0`

```
paste0("\\b", patterns, "\\b")
```

Comment: Did you mean `paste0(e1, "\\b", e2)` ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I meant the translation from the link `"\\b" %s+% patterns %s+% "\\b"` with `paste0("\\b", patterns, "\\b")`

Comment: Right! Understood